# What does childbearing have to do with the salvation of a woman?

Tags: exegesis, soteriology, genesis, women, 1-timothy

Verse concerning saved:

> <sup>12</sup>But I suffer not a woman to teach, nor to usurp authority over the man, but to be in silence. <sup>13</sup>For Adam was first formed, then Eve. <sup>14</sup>And Adam was not deceived, but the woman being deceived was in the transgression. <sup>15</sup>Notwithstanding she shall be saved in childbearing, if they continue in faith and charity and holiness with sobriety. -- *1 Timothy 2*

Related verse:

> <sup>16</sup>Unto the woman he said, I will greatly multiply thy sorrow and thy conception; in sorrow thou shalt bring forth children; and thy desire shall be to thy husband, and he shall rule over thee. -- *Genesis 3*

Question: Verse 14 clearly addresses Eve eating the apple. Since Salvation is through what Christ accomplished on the cross alone -- what does childbearing have to do with 'she shall be saved in childbearing' ?

Comment: This is an interesting question, but there is a lot already written on it - have you done any research on this issue?

Comment: Question: Why do you think the two passages you've cited are related? Question: Do you automatically assume that the word "saved" means only made fit for heaven through the new birth? Question: Why not include in your question a verse such as Genesis 3:15, which speaks of the seed of the woman (which is a deliberate contradiction in terms, since "seed" is always linked with the man and not the woman)? Question: Could Christ's birth have anything to do with the woman's being saved? Question: What does a woman's silence have to do with her being saved? Selah.

Comment: [Are women really saved by childbearing according to 1 Timothy 2:15?](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/1674/3555)

Comment: Here's another interesting question to add to @rhetorician's list: does the "thou shalt" make bringing forth children a commandment?

Comment: According to whom?  Since this doesn't specify a tradition, I'm voting to close.

Answer (score 0):

As timf quoted:

> they will be saved [eternally] if they continue in faith and love and holiness with self-control, [saved indeed] through the Childbearing or by the birth of the divine Child. - Amplified

Childbearing resulted in the birth of Jesus. 
If you look at "she", the "woman" as an image not for each woman as an individual, but as womanhood as a whole, or as Eve specifically, who is mentioned in the verse before, than she, the woman is saved through childbearing - the birth of Jesus.
Or as you can already see promised in Genesis 3, when God addresses the snake:

> And I will put enmity
>       between you and the woman,
>       and between your offspring and hers;
>   he will crush your head,
>       and you will strike his heel - Genesis 3:15.

Eve's offspring - singular - will crush the snake's head and destroy it.

Now that still leaves the part of the verse where it says "if they continue in faith and charity and holiness with sobriety" ... and that may still sound like this salvation requires works. However notice what it mentions first in this list after childbearing, which as explained refers to Jesus: faith. This faith and resulting life change then results in charity and holiness and sobriety - which are things God does works in us through His Holy Spirit - see for example Gal. 5:22-23.

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE! And thanks for taking the site tour. Thanks also for offering an answer here. Does this answer represent any particular group or denomination of Christians? If so, it would make the answer a better fit for the site. See: [How we are different than other sites](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites). Meanwhile, I hope you'll stick around and [register an account](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/why-register) here.

Answer (score -1):

**What does childbearing have to do with the salvation of a woman?**

This is an example of the benefit an expanded translation can have over word for word translations.

> 1 Timothy 2:15  Notwithstanding she shall be saved in childbearing, if
>   they continue in faith and charity and holiness with sobriety. - KJV
>
> 1 Timothy 2:15  Nevertheless [the sentence put upon women of pain in
>   motherhood does not hinder their souls' salvation, and] they will be
>   saved [eternally] if they continue in faith and love and holiness with
>   self-control, [saved indeed] through the Childbearing or by the birth
>   of the divine Child. - Amplified

Answer (score -2):

Background: God uses trials and pains to perfect his people so that they become more like Christ (Rom. 5:3-4). This is the salvation known as the sanctification of the believer, or "being saved."

Answer: In the case of this verse, the woman can find her relationship with God strengthened even with the pain of childbirth if she continues through it in faith.